# CSS two skewed container slider

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-animations, skew

I have unconventionall project and thinking is that possible to do that.

I have 2 containers which are separated with border. Both of have skew. Picture or maybe text are not skewed - of course to have normal perspective i'll use opposite skew in content.

When i click to left or right container the container will animate to full monitor width

Do you have some idea how to built that and how design css correctly?

Screens: 
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVSa4.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? Perhaps a jsFiddle example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1cvLmawh/

Comment: If you mean something like the lower boxes here: https://developer.chrome.com/devsummit/ , the developer did a nice video here: http://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/

Comment: No, it's not like that. Everything will be work great but skew ruin everything. I guess it can't be written only with css and js, maybe some pictures will be the best solutions

Comment: You will need to use some JS to capture the click events, but the animation and everything can be done using CSS3 - You can add/remove animation classes etc. to match your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point on how it could work.

```css
div {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.a {
  background-image: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8713/16556277604_bb297ec7a6_z_d.jpg');
}
.a > div {
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  width: 220px;
  transform: skewX(-20deg)
}
.a > div > div {
  background-image: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8736/16982940820_01564cbb99_z_d.jpg');
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why .a > div > div has margin-left: -40px?

Comment: @AdamRudnicki because otherwise the bottom left corner of the right picture wouldn't reach the white skewed border

Comment: @AdamRudnicki Sure. As said, my example was just a quick proof of concept and not a complete solution.

Comment: In my opinion that solution isn't good when you need to have that container adjustable to window with. It will be good idea when will be exist some calculations for backward and forward (margin-left: -40px, right: -40px). Maybe solution is javasript?